# Showing one label for a split polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling

I have a few polygons representing crop fields.
I have split each one based on an aerial map for ease of area measurements but now when I show labels for each polygon (with block names) it creates a label for each part of the polygon (same label for each part) and the map becomes overloaded with labels.
Is there a way to put one label per polygon (say in between all parts of the polygon)?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck the option `Label every part of multi-part-features` in the last tab (rendering tab) of label settings at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, this was embarrassingly simple.